# How to force open a new Tab/Window in Lightning Experience from anchor links?

Tags: lightning-experience, bug, hyperlink

I have a visualforce page that has links in it, but those links are specifically set to `target="_blank"`, and they open new tab in Aloha interface, but in Lightning Experience they open the links in same browser tab and redirects user to that link.

Is this a bug in Lightning Experience? And is there a workaround to open a new tab for Lightning Experience?

My anchor link is pretty much very simpler:

```
<a href="/<recordid>" target="_blank">Open (New Window)</a>
```

This would open new window in Aloha environment but not in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you found the solution, but I got in the same situation, and I noticed when we pass the full url it opens in a new tab or window.

```
<a href="https://test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/<recordid>" target="_blank">Open (New Window)</a>
```

Also, I noticed that if we pass an underscore in the begin, it will open a new tab as well.

```
<a href="_/<recordid>" target="_blank">Open (New Window)</a>
```

Comment: '_' in href attribute isn't required i believe. 
`<a href="/<recordid>" target="_blank">Open (New Window)</a>` worked for me.