# lightning:dataTable URL won't open in new window

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I've got a `lightning:dataTable` I'm working on for a client. One of the columns is of type URL, and it links to a Visualforce PDF. It is defined in the `columns` attribute as:

```
{
  sortable:true, 
  label: 'Invoice No.',
  fieldName: 'urlField__c',
  type: 'url' , 
  typeAttributes: { 
    label: { fieldName: 'Invoice_Number__c' }, 
    target:'_blank'
  }
}
```

When the component loads, I can "Inspect Element" in Chrome and see that the URL correctly has `target=_blank`. However clicking it always opens the PDF in the same window under the Lightning header instead of popping open a new one. Then the user has to hit the back button to return to where they were which is not intuitive.

Is there anything I can do to force it to a new window?

Comment: Could it be related to this bug someone else mentioned? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157552/how-to-force-open-a-new-tab-window-in-lightning-experience-from-anchor-links

Are the urls all relative urls? If so, does adding an underscore before the '/'  make a difference?

Comment: All relative URLs, yes, to a Visualforce PDF. I have not tried the underscore. In fact I ended up trying a bit of a silly hack... I changed the column to type "button", selected "base" so it appears like a link with no actual button, and then used an `onrowaction` handler. But I'll see if the underscore might help too.

Comment: If I attempt to add a underscore to the field containing the URL, the browser no longer interprets it properly.

Comment: And if I attempt to do it as an absolute URL link, that too opens in the same window.

Comment: So I just tried testing this out in an org, and when I have a url field with target: '_blank' and a relative URL I get a modal popup that says "We'd like to open the Salesforce page https://[url here]... in a new tab. Because of your browser settings, we need your permission first. Is it possible you have popups completely blocked by your browser or other security software? One interesting thing is that when I cancelled the popup instead of accepting it, I started seeing the behavior you reported and clearing my browser data didn't cause the Salesforce modal to show up again.

Comment: Are you testing in a `lightning:dataTable` or with a bare URL? I don't have much control over how dataTable renders the URL. The only way to pass the underscore in is to add it to the field it's going to render. If I put something like `_/apex/PageName?param=x` into the field, then by the time dataTable renders it, it's interpreting it as `http://_/apex/PageName?param=x` which is obviously not going to work.

Comment: I did my own testing that I mentioned using `lightning:dataTable`. The previous suggestion was just from a related question, I had not tested it on this component. Did your button workaround work?

Comment: Yes the button workaround is "good enough". It looks approximately like a link. However it does not display a URL on hover like a link does, can't be right-clicked etc.

Answer (score 0):

typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Invoice_Number__c' }, target: '_top'}},